# RHEL 8: openssh-server build from src tarball and distribute the executable?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, openssh, make

I have a task to build and deploy openssh-server 8.6 on a number of RHEL8 systems running openssh-server 8.0 (this is due to a security compliance finding).  Unfortunately there does not appear to be an RPM package that suits our version requirement.

If I must build from src tarball, can I do the build process (./configure, make, make install) *on one system*, and then simply copy the executable sshd (/usr/local/sbin/sshd) to all of the other systems? Or must I do the complete build process from src tarball on all the systems needing this upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

*Technically,* yes, you can always simply copy binaries freely between systems that have the nec­es­sary libraries present. (After all, that's literally what happens when you install RPMs in the first place – the binary is built once by RHEL, then installed everywhere.)

But as a sysadmin, it's a bit of a management nightmare when the package manager says X, but the system actually has Y. It's bad when you have two of the same thing (old sshd in /usr, new sshd in /usr/local, very easy to accidentally start the wrong one) – and it's even worse if you copy the new sshd binary *on top* of the new one, and then sometime later it goes poof because another admin just installed a "critical openssh 8.0 security update" RPM on top.

Do it properly by *building a RPM* of the new version, which correctly indicates the version it is, and allows the package manager to keep track of which files belong to it. For example, you could use the openssh.spec file [from Fedora](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/openssh/blob/rawhide/f/openssh.spec) (which is conveniently at version 8.7), or the one that [comes with OpenSSH sources](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/contrib/redhat/openssh.spec) (always the latest version), or even the one from RHEL (manually edit it to build 8.6 instead of 8.0).

The main tool for turning a .spec into a .rpm is `rpmbuild`. Here's a [Red Hat intro](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/create-rpm-package) and [another one](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/03/18/rpm-packaging-guide-creating-rpm) and a [general .spec guide](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/).

Though still, that's only "proper" in terms of basic package management. In your situation there are still other problems with it, such as the fact that the 8.0 package from RHEL *is maintained as part of RHEL* – as long as RHEL8 as a whole is current, Red Hat will make sure any security fixes present in later releases get backported to the OpenSSH package that comes with the distro. (Chances are, if you're large enough to deal with security audits, you might even be *paying* Red Hat for RHEL support.)

But once you install your own version, you're on your own – if there's a security fix in OpenSSH 8.9 you have to remember to install it, if it has a security fix *and* is somehow incompatible with RHEL8, you have to somehow take care of it. (Not to mention that unless you're using the RHEL8 openssh.spec as the basis, you'd be losing the bunch of SELinux patches, FIPS-compliance patches, and various odd bugfixes that the RHEL version has.)

So the end result is that you'll most likely become *less* security-compliant by doing this.

Comment: Thanks. Makes a lot of sense. Looking into the docs for building custom RPMs, it's not trivial by any means, and as you say, can actually compromise the ability to stay in line with various versioning events in the system's lifecycle.

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you start from scratch or whether you take an existing 8.7 spec from Fedora and just run `rpmbuild` on it...

Comment: I started looking at using the 8.0 .spec file. I was able to extract it with `rpm2cpio openssh-8.0p1-6.el8_4.2.src.rpm  | cpio -ivd openssh.spec`, and placed  it in my SPECS directory. It's kind of daunting to know what to edit and what to leave alone, since this is based on an older version than what I'm building.  I know I can cut out the Changelog, but what about the Patches ?  Starting to think it might be safer/easier to simply install the tar.gz with `make`  and modify my service files.  Would taking the 8.7 spec from Fedora reduce the amounts of edits needed in .spec?

Comment: Well, if you take the 8.7 one, do you even need to edit it at all? Were you required to install 8.6 specifically, or just "8.6 or higher"? If the latter, then just build Fedora's 8.7 as-is (or in fact get the already built RPM from Fedora's repository?) – that way at least you're using something that was already tested.